# Ubuntu - "sudo iptables" command works in terminal, doesn't work in bash script

Tags: linux, scripting, sudo

I'm using a simple terminal command that adds a rule to iptables and it executes without problems:

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "facebook.com" --algo kmp -j REJECT`

When I run that command in a bash script, it returns `sudo: ./script.sh: command not found`

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "facebook.com" --algo kmp -j REJECT
```

Comment: Is `script.sh` executable? `chmod +x script.sh`

Comment: Apparently it wasn't. It works after I changed permission. I thought all scripts are executable by default. Thanks!

Comment: @MarinLeontenko a script is just another file. By that logic, all files would be executable by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a script is not executable, one has to call it with an appropriate shell like `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`. This will ignore the shebang line and the script will be executed with the calling shell.

```
sudo /bin/sh ./script.sh
```

To run the script as inteded by OP you have to give the script execution rights.

```
chmod +x script.sh
sudo ./script.sh
```

In this case the script is executed with the shell of the shebang line.

Comment: I believe that you can also use `. <scriptname>` to run it in the currently running shell. That is how I executed scripts back in the day on my dialup Unix shell.